# Cassandra Bulk Load - NoHostAvailableException

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are doing hourly aggregations using Spark SQL and Cassandra on huge data. We have developed a Java client which runs every hour to do the aggregations using Spark SQL. For historic loads, When we running this program for 10 days (240 Hours) of data, after around 100 hours processed, Cassandra is failing with below error:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)

what's causing Cassandra to fail ?

Comment: what version of the spark connector / datastax java driver are you using?

Comment: We are using  spark-cassandra connector 1.2.0-rc3 jar. Spark version is 1.2.1 and cassandra version is 2.0.13

Comment: See Russ's post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058355/datastax-enterprise-savetocassandra-generate-a-lot-of-hinted-handoff

Answer (score 2):

This is resolved after configuring higher values for `"spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms"` and `"spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms"`